# Make a matrix to preserve a square aspect ratio when printing

Tags: formatting, amsmath, matrices

For some reason, in a new paper that I'm writing, all matrices look wider than usual, loosing the squared aspect ratio they originally had. I'm copying the exact same code from an old paper to the new one.

On the left is how latex is printing them now, on the right side how I want them and how are printed in the old paper.

[image]

How can I solve it in a general way for all the matrixes in the document?

EDIT: Im leaving here all the preambles, as I dont't really know what could be causing the issue. https://shrib.com/?v=nc#DarwinGroundFinch7zXOK65

An example of the code I use for a new matrix:

```
\begin{equation}
\vn{M}=
\left( \begin{array}{c:cc:c}
\vn{\tilde{M}} &  &  & \vn{L}_{AB} \\  \hdashline
& \vn{M}^{c}_{B} & \vn{M}^{cb}_{B} &  \\
& \vn{M}^{bc}_{A} & \vn{M}^{b}_{A} & -\vn{L}_{BA} \\ \hdashline         
\vn{L}^{t}_{AB} &       &   -\vn{L}^{t}_{BA}  & \\   % 
\end{array} \right) 
\label{eq:M_modal_matrix}
\end{equation}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! Probably, there's a difference in the preambles between the old and the new paper. Could you post a small , yet complete, code reproducing the current layout?

Comment: Dear Bernard, thanks for answering, just left more info at the main post!

Comment: How is the `\vn` command?  It is not defined in the linked preamble.

Comment: It's just for formatting math symbols more easily \newcommand{\vn}[1]{\mbox{\boldmath${#1}$}} Anyway, egreg just found the solution. Thanks both for helping! Hope in the near future I am proficient enough to be able to answer other questions in exchange.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess that you changed your setting of line spacing.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,arydshln}
\usepackage{setspace}

\newcommand{\vn}[1]{#1}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\vn{M}=
\left( \begin{array}{c:cc:c}
\vn{\tilde{M}} &  &  & \vn{L}_{AB} \\  \hdashline
& \vn{M}^{c}_{B} & \vn{M}^{cb}_{B} &  \\
& \vn{M}^{bc}_{A} & \vn{M}^{b}_{A} & -\vn{L}_{BA} \\ \hdashline         
\vn{L}^{t}_{AB} &       &   -\vn{L}^{t}_{BA}  & \\   % 
\end{array} \right) 
\end{equation}

\doublespacing

\begin{equation}
\vn{M}=
\left( \begin{array}{c:cc:c}
\vn{\tilde{M}} &  &  & \vn{L}_{AB} \\  \hdashline
& \vn{M}^{c}_{B} & \vn{M}^{cb}_{B} &  \\
& \vn{M}^{bc}_{A} & \vn{M}^{b}_{A} & -\vn{L}_{BA} \\ \hdashline         
\vn{L}^{t}_{AB} &       &   -\vn{L}^{t}_{BA}  & \\   % 
\end{array} \right) 
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Since you seem to be using `\setstretch{1.1}` now, you can locally redefine `\arraystretch` to yield the same result as with `\doublespacing`.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,arydshln}
\usepackage{setspace}

\newcommand{\vn}[1]{#1}

\setstretch{1.1}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation}
\vn{M}=
\left( \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\begin{array}{c:cc:c}
\vn{\tilde{M}} &  &  & \vn{L}_{AB} \\  \hdashline
& \vn{M}^{c}_{B} & \vn{M}^{cb}_{B} &  \\
& \vn{M}^{bc}_{A} & \vn{M}^{b}_{A} & -\vn{L}_{BA} \\ \hdashline         
\vn{L}^{t}_{AB} &       &   -\vn{L}^{t}_{BA}  & \\   % 
\end{array} \right) 
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

[image]